# Gitlab Server Hook version 16.1

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-ci, hook

[Related with this issue](https://forum.gitlab.com/t/problem-configuring-pre-recieve-server-hook/89651)
The server-hook dont work

Im trying to create a server-hook in gitlab.
The objective is to create a hook that fires when any user push.
We tried several things:

1. Uncomment the custom hooks dir line

Follow the official docs : [guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html#choose-a-server-hook-directory)

Go to the gitlab.rb(configuration file), then uncomment the line:

> gitaly['configuration'][:hooks][:custom_hooks_dir]='var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/custom_hooks'

This is the folder where server-hooks are supposed to be placed.

Following the [guide](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html#create-the-global-server-hook) :
Create the folder pre-receive.d :absolute( var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/custom_hooks/pre-receive.d)

https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html#create-the-global-server-hook

Then add the script with the shebang, for example:

> var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/custom_hooks/demohook

```
#!/bin/sh
echo "GL-HOOK-ERR: My custom error message.";
exit 1
```

Then gitlab reconfigure, fails saids its deprecated(eventhough is in the official guide).

2.Adding gitaly configuration to the file
Found that first way of configuration could be obsolete, tried adding to gitlab.rb:

```
gitaly['configuration'] = {
  hooks: {
    # gitaly['custom_hooks_dir']
    custom_hooks_dir: '/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/custom_hooks'
  }
```

}

Nothing works.
Any help is welcome.

Comment: Does [this](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/administration/server_hooks.html) help? Did you test if your script is called properly?

Comment: I tried server-hooks part, in wich according to the docs, you just have to check that it does not match the pattern (*~), so i called something like demohook

Comment: IS there any permission issue for `/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/custom_hooks` directory. The directory and its contents must be owned by the GitLab user and group, and the permissions must be set to 755.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem.
Reviewing forums we have come to the conclusion that it is a permissions issue.
As the directory does not have sufficient capacities, the error does not even appear in the log.
Fixed issue with a chmod command on the directory. @VonC

Comment: OK I will post an answer shortly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [commented](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76668730/gitlab-server-hook-version-16-1?noredirect=1#comment135204647_76668730), the issue is a permission one for the folder `/var/opt/gitlab/gitaly/custom_hooks`.

The OP confirms:

> Reviewing forums we have come to the conclusion that it is a permissions issue. As the directory does not have sufficient capacities, the error does not even appear in the log. Fixed issue with a `chmod` command on the directory.